# Provide access to Github private repo from machinery

Tags: git, github

I have a private git repo which I'm admin of and I want to provide machinery access (application)
to it. I don't find any entry to provide some sort of token, I just see webhook and `deploy keys` (for deployed keys from where I should provide key? how can I generate one?),
I want to generate some token and provide it that the program will have read access to it, how it could be done?

I see this be this is in scope of **user** but I need in scope of **repository** …

https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-3-personal-access-tokens/#targetText=To%20create%20a%20personal%20access,and%20enable%20the%20repo%20checkbox.

https://github.blog/2015-06-16-read-only-deploy-keys/

I dont have the button `add deployed keys` as I dont have any keys yet
I just have hte button `add key`

https://superuser.com/questions/1314064/read-only-access-to-github-repo-via-ssh-key

I try to generate with

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user@mail.com"`

and took the generated key and put it on keys and I got error:

`Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've pasted the private half of the key into the box, not the public half.  If you're generating an RSA SSH key, your private part is likely in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and the public part is in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (note the ".pub" part).  If you paste the public part of the key into the box, you should be able to use the private part as normal to access the repository.